# Copy specific worksheets to new Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel file.

I need to open it, select specific sheets from it, and convert those sheets to a PDF format. I am able to convert the whole excel file, I just don't know how to convert only the specific sheets.

My idea is to copy specific sheets from an existing file to a new temporary file, and convert that whole new temporary file to PDF.

Maybe there's an easier way?

My code so far is =>

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    public static void ExportExcel(string infile, string outfile, int[] worksheets)
    {
        Excel.Application excelApp = null;
        Excel.Application newExcelApp = null;
        try
        {
            excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Workbooks.Open(infile);
            //((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet).PageSetup.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;  

            excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, outfile);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (excelApp != null)
            {
                excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                excelApp.SaveWorkspace();
                excelApp.Quit();
            }
         }
    }
```

Maybe the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method can be set to consider only specific pages (sheets) while converting?

If not, how do I copy the sheets from one file to another?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply copy the file to the new destination, open the destination, remove the unwanted sheets and export. This is an example (tested) of my idea.

```
// infile is the excel file, outfile is the pdf to build, sheetToExport is the name of the sheet
public static void ExportExcel(string infile, string outfile, string sheetToExport) 
{ 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new     
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    try  
    {  
        string tempFile = Path.ChangeExtension(outfile, "XLS"); 
        File.Copy(infile, tempFile, true); 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook excelWorkbook = 
                                excelApp.Workbooks.Open(tempFile);  

        for(int x = excelApp.Sheets.Count; x > 0; x--) 
        { 
            _Worksheet sheet = (_Worksheet)excelApp.Sheets[x];
            if(sheet != null && sheet.Name != sheetToExport) 
                sheet.Delete(); 
        }  
        excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, outfile);  
    }  
    finally  
    {  
        if (excelApp != null)  
        {  
             excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;  
             excelApp.SaveWorkspace();  
             excelApp.Quit();  
         }  
     }      
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to just print the sheets you want from the original file.  I fired up the Macro Recorder, selected a couple of sheets, and Saved As to PDF.  Here's the code:

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\doug\Documents\Book1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

When I changed the selected sheets and ran again it worked as expected.

What's strange is that in the actual Save As dialog, you can go to Options and check "Selected Sheets."  That's not available as a parameter to ExportAsFixedFormat, but it was automatically selected in the dialog, and maybe is the default also when called.